# Using parser combinators to collate lines of text

Tags: regex, scala, parser-combinators

I'm trying to parse a text file using parser combinators. I want to capture the index and text in a class called `Example`. Here's a test showing the form on an input file:

```
object Test extends ParsComb with App {
  val input = """
0)
blah1
blah2
blah3
1)
blah4
blah5
END
"""
  println(parseAll(examples, input))
}
```

And here's my attempt that doesn't work:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers

case class Example(index: Int, text: String)

class ParsComb extends RegexParsers {
  def examples: Parser[List[Example]] = rep(divider~example) ^^ 
                                          {_ map {case d ~ e => Example(d,e)}}
  def divider:  Parser[Int]           = "[0-9]+".r <~ ")"    ^^ (_.toInt)
  def example:  Parser[String]        = ".*".r <~ (divider | "END") 
}
```

It fails with:

```
[4.1] failure: `END' expected but `b' found

blah2

^
```

I'm just starting out with these so I don't have much clue what I'm doing. I think the problem could be with the `".*".r` regex not doing multi-line. How can I change this so that it parses correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- What does the error message mean?

According to your grammar definition, `".*".r <~ (divider | "END")`, you told to the parser that, an `example` should followed either by a `divider` or a `END`. After parsing blah1, the parser tried to find `divider` and failed, then tried `END`, failed again, there're no other options available, so the `END` here was the last alternative of the production value, so from the parser's perspective, it expected `END`, but it soon found, the next input was `blah2` from the 4th line.

- How to fix it?

Try to be close to your implementation, the grammar in your case should be:

```
examples ::= {divider example}
divider  ::= Integer")"
example  ::= {literal ["END"]}
```

and I think parsing "example" into `List[String]` makes more sense, anyway, it's up to you.

The problem is your `example` parser, it should be a repeatable literal.

So ,

```
class ParsComb extends RegexParsers {
  def examples: Parser[List[Example]] = rep(divider ~ example) ^^ { _ map { case d ~ e => Example(d, e) } }
  def divider: Parser[Int] = "[0-9]+".r <~ ")" ^^ (_.toInt)
  def example: Parser[List[String]] = rep("[\\w]*(?=[\\r\\n])".r <~ opt("END"))
}
```

the regex `(?=[\\r\\n])` means it's a positive lookahead and would match characters that followed by `\r` or `\n`.

the parse result is:

> [10.1] parsed: List(Example(0,List(blah1, blah2, blah3)),
>   Example(1,List(blah4, blah5)))

If you want to parse it into a String(instead of `List[String]`), just add a transform function for example: `^^ {_ mkString "\n"}`

Comment: Thanks, great answer - please post more to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 2):

Your parser can't process newline character, your `example` parser eliminates next `divider` and your `example` regex matches `divider` and "END" string.

Try this:

```
object ParsComb extends RegexParsers { 
  def examples: Parser[List[Example]] = rep(divider~example) <~ """END\n?""".r ^^ {_ map {case d ~ e => Example(d,e)}} 
  def divider: Parser[Int] = "[0-9]+".r <~ ")\n" ^^ (_.toInt) 
  def example: Parser[String] = rep(str) ^^ {_.mkString}
  def str: Parser[String] = """.*\n""".r ^? { case s if simpleLine(s) => s}

  val div = """[0-9]+\)\n""".r
  def simpleLine(s: String) = s match {
    case div() => false
    case "END\n" => false
    case _ => true
  }

  def apply(s: String) = parseAll(examples, s)
}
```

Result:

```
scala> ParsComb(input)
res3: ParsComb.ParseResult[List[Example]] =
[10.1] parsed: List(Example(0,blah1
blah2
blah3
), Example(1,blah4
blah5
))
```

Comment: Thanks - I will have a play with this later to ensure I understand what's going on!

Answer (score 1):

> I think the problem could be with the ".*".r regex not doing
>   multi-line.

Exactly. Use the dotall modifier (strangely called "s"):

```
def example:  Parser[String]        = "(?s).*".r <~ (divider | "END")
```