# Discarding the remaining input using parser combinators

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

I just want to parse the following string up until the `END` token then ignore the rest:

```
val input = """
0)
blah1
blah2
blah3
1)
blah4
blah5
END
blah6
"""
```

Using

```
object Pars extends RegexParsers {
  def strings: Parser[List[String]] = rep(str) <~ end
  def str:     Parser[String]       = ".*".r
  def end:     Parser[String]       = "END" <~ rep(".*".r)
}

Pars.parseAll(Pars.strings, input)
```

goes into an infinite loop and an OutOfMemoryError. What am I doing wrong, and how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do not use `parseAll`. Use `parse` instead.

As for the problem you have, you are saying the same thing twice in a few places:

```
rep(".*".r)
```

`rep` and `*` both mean "any number of repetitions". Now, `.*` matches the empty string, so `rep` then proceed to match an infinite number of empty strings.

Here's how I'd rewrite it:

```
object Pars extends RegexParsers {
  def strings: Parser[List[String]] = 
    ( "END" ^^^ Nil 
    | ".+".r ~ strings ^^ { case head ~ tail => head :: tail }
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was useful. I've cobbled something together that works using this and senia's excellent answer to my other question http://stackoverflow.com/a/11113833/770361

Comment: Thanks Daniel, your updated answer is great! I thought there should be some way to automatically deal with the line ends, but didn't know how.

Comment: I've found a problem with this: if the `END` token isn't present, instead of a parsing failure, we get a stack overflow. Any ideas?

Comment: @LuigiPlinge Make it `.+` instead of `.*`. Since newlines will be treated as spaces and skipped, empty lines are not a concern. I'll even edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
object Pars extends RegexParsers { 
  def strings: Parser[List[String]] = rep(str) <~ "END"
  def str:     Parser[String]       = """.*\r?\n""".r ^? { 
    case s if !(s matches """END\r?\n""") => s.replaceAll("""[\r\n]""", "")
  }
}

Pars.parse(Pars.strings, input) // note parse, not parseAll
  //[9.4] parsed: List(0), blah1, blah2, blah3, 1), blah4, blah5)
```

The key thing seems to be that you can't just match on `.*` - you have to match on `.*\r?\n` to get a line of text (the `\r` is required for Windows-format files). I also tried `^.*$` which I'd have thought would work, but doesn't. Neither does `".*" <~ """\r?\n""".r`.

(`^?` is similar to `^^` except it takes a partial function.)

If anyone can make this more elegant, please let me know!

Comment: I see no reason to match against `\r\n`. It should be skipped as whitespace by regex parsers. I'd just write `strings` differently: `"END" | ".*".r ~ strings ^^ { case "END" => Nil case other ~ list => other :: list }`.

Comment: There's an error of precedence in my comment. See my edited answer.